# Change data binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My English is not good, sorry.

Here is what I want to do:

`<button class="add"></button>   <input type="text" ng-model="title">`

When I click on `<button>`, it adds one `<p ng-bind="title"></p>` label into the HTML page, so when I write something into `<input>` AngularJS helps me to change the title in `<p>`.
If I add more than one `<p>` label，I wonder how can I make only the last one `<p>`'s title to change when I write something into `<input>`, instead of changing all `<p>` via AngularJs `ng-model="title"` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="main">
  <button class="add">add</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="title"/>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('main',['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.title = '';
}])
.directive('button',['$compile',function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function(scope,element) {
         element.bind('click',function() {
            var p = $compile('<p ng-bind="title"></p>')(scope);
            p.insertBefore(element);
         });
       }
   }
}])
```

Comment: put your code here please

Comment: Little bit of code would help us to answer. if you bind multiple `p` to the title it will show multiple times. why don't you add it to the last `p` instead?

Comment: English is good. "Your" English is not good. ;) JK

Comment: @atmfans you could also provide a jsfiddle or jsbin to be easier to help

Comment: i want to use only one `<input>` to modify   multiple  `<p>·`element inner text   ,but those `<p>` inner text are not different

Comment: @simon,@Nilesh,   code has been added

Comment: Why don't you just have an array of inputs in your controller which you add to every time you click the input?  Then you can just do this:

    `<p ng-repeat="input in inputCollection">{{input.title}}</p>`

Every time you add to the collection (on controller scope) another <p> element will be added.

Comment: Its giving me insertBefore is not a function error

Comment: @IfOnly   add library  jQuery 1.11.3   and  ` jQuery(p).insertBefore(element)`

Comment: @simon,@Kutyel,@Nilesh,@natwallbank,@lfOnly,  js Bin: https://jsbin.com/xuroja/6/edit?html,css,js,output